# What normally happens to a Katra?

Tags: star-trek, vulcan

In *Wrath of Khan*

> at the end Spock performs a mind meld with McCoy, transferring his Katra to McCoy

Then in *Search for Spock*

> we see that McCoy's mind gets 'scrambled' as he likes to call it, basically suffering from what looks like a form of multiple personality disorder.

In *Search for Spock*, Sarek tells Jim:

> I assumed he had mind-melded with you. It is the Vulcan way when the body's end is near.

([source](http://www.scifiscripts.com/scripts/Trek/Star_Trek_III.htm))

So it seems to be a normal Vulcan thing to transfer one's Katra into someone else.  Considering the negative side effects, **what normally happens to a Vulcan katra once it has been transferred?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The page on [Katras on Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Katra) is very useful for this.

The opening line on the aforementioned page explains that a katra *can* be transferred to a person moments before death, but the existence of [Katric arks](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Katric_ark) suggests that it need not be transferred to a person.

The 'Vulcan way' that Sarek is referring to is probably supported later when he explains that all that Spock knew was lost.  Consider the following excerpt from the Memory Alpha page:

> When a katra was transferred to someone, **he or she will benefit from
>   the experiences of the person the katra came from**.

Hence, this 'Vulcan way' when it comes to death that Sarek refers to is probably regarding the transferring of one's experiences to help the next generations build upon that which was learned in former generations.

The side-effects that McCoy suffered from apply to other species, but not Vulcans:

> Non-Vulcans might experience side effects like a form of multiple
>   personality. Humans were especially vulnerable because of the severe
>   shock a transfer can give to their nervous system.

Normally, it would seem, the transfer of a Katra is not done in the hopes of making a Vulcan immortal i.e. passing their katra down from generation to generation into a new body or anything like that:

> The transfer of someone's katra was not regularly practiced and was
>   only done in special circumstances.

It seems that **normally, a katra was passed to another Vulcan to pass on their experiences and knowledge rather than to try and immortalise themselves**

Comment: your first quote "The existence of the katra was controversial; many Vulcans thought it was nothing more than a myth" should be excluded and the memory alpha site is essentially wrong for even including it, since they have proof that katras are real in startrek and vulcans would all exceot this fact, as it would be only logical too. that quote is only valid pre enterprise before Archer finds Surak. when archer finds surak its proves Katras are real, and by the time of spock had re-learned how to actually do it themselves.